# How to find out how many times a minute a function is executed in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash, hex, mining

I have a function and I want to know how many times this function is executed per minute

For example, write every 1 minute :

204 hash/m

This is my function

```
def test_hash_abc(difficulty):
    x = 0
    while 1:
        y = hashlib.sha256("hello world{}".format(x).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
        if y[0:len(difficulty)] == str(difficulty) :
            print(y)
            x+= 1
        else : x+= 1


test_hash_abc('ffff')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function contains `while 1` which is an infinite loop in your case (as you never break out of the loop). I assume you want to see how many times per minute the code *under* `while 1` runs. In that case, try the following:

```
import hashlib
import time

def test_hash_abc(difficulty):
    x = 0
    counter = 0
    while 1:
        start = time.time()
        while time.time() - start < 60:
            y = hashlib.sha256("hello world{}".format(x).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
            if y[0:len(difficulty)] == str(difficulty) :
                print(y)
                x+= 1
            else:
                x+= 1
            counter += 1
        print('{} hash/m'.format(counter))

test_hash_abc('ffff')
```

Note that removing `print(y)` will result in a higher execution number per minute.

Comment: Thanks
But after showing the hash rate

The function does not continue
I want to continue

Answer (score 0):

cant say about per minute but you can use `line_profiler` module which have time per hit table on line basis